# What's the correct name for Guava module in GWT application?

Tags: java, gwt, guava

There are 2 jars in GWT SDK: **gwt-user.jar** and **gwt-dev.jar**. Since they're in my classpath I can use them without problems.

However when I tried to use gwt bundled guava (com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common)  I get following error at clientside runtime:

> No source code is available for type `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.Lists`; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Yes I probably did forget to inherit **required** module, but I don't have idea which one is that for guava :)

I inspected jars and found lot of .gwt.xml files, but in gwt-user.jar and no guava sign there :O

**Update**: It seems to be problem having both guava.jar and guava-gwt.jar @ classpath. So I use only guava-gwt.jar now, but this is logged when launching application. Compiler complains about javax.annotation and stuff like that ... I can't paste here full log due to character count limitation.

```
 [DEBUG] [databasemanager] - Validating newly compiled units
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 20: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 51: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 51: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 60: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Equivalences.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 20: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 73: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 73: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 78: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 83: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 83: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 87: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Function.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 19: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 43: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 55: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Functions.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 25: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 108: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 137: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 145: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 155: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 200: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 241: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 266: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 273: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 277: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 281: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Joiner.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 28: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 113: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 113: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 147: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 147: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 171: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 171: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Objects.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 25: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 50: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 50: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 160: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 160: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 188: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 203: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 86: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 112: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 113: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 143: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 169: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 170: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 202: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 227: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 228: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 298: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 348: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 413: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Predicate.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 21: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 45: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 57: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/super/com/google/common/base/Predicates.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 29: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 171: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 209: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 214: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 219: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 224: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 248: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 282: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 314: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 341: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 362: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 368: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 399: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 432: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Strings.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 26: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 45: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 56: Nullable cannot be resolved to
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 26: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 189: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 197: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/AbstractBiMap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 31: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 99: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 99: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/AbstractLinkedIterator.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 45: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/AbstractListMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 25: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 60: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 71: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 83: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 94: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 94: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 115: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultiset.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 36: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 225: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 230: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 244: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 266: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 322: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapEntry.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 43: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 42: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 154: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 172: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 176: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 186: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 186: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 193: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 193: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 204: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 213: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 213: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 231: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 266: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 293: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 335: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 349: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 362: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 362: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 391: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 392: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 457: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 630: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 640: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 641: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 687: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 688: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 817: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 818: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 900: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 1284: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 1355: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 1464: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMultiset.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 29: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 61: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 80: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 152: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/AbstractSetMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 25: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 58: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 80: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 94: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 127: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/AbstractSortedSetMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 25: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 64: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 76: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 46: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 46: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 65: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 65: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ByFunctionOrdering.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 27: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 49: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 23: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 58: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ComparatorOrdering.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 28: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 55: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 26: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 71: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 71: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 109: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 109: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 112: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 113: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 113: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 149: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 149: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/EnumHashBiMap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 75: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 79: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ExplicitOrdering.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 61: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingCollection.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 26: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 117: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 156: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingImmutableCollection.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 21: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 42: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 27: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 104: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 145: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 157: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 214: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingListMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 23: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 43: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 47: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 29: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 117: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 149: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 198: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 222: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 263: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMapEntry.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 26: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 76: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 92: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 26: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 54: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 54: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 58: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 62: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 70: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 98: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 98: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 102: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 118: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMultiset.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 27: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 80: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 103: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 129: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 271: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSet.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 56: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 71: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSetMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 45: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 49: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSortedMap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 27: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 107: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 131: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSortedSet.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 27: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 104: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 127: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSortedSetMultimap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 44: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 48: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 29: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 114: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 114: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 118: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 122: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 126: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 130: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 130: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 134: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 139: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 139: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 24: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 79: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 79: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 83: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 83: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 25: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 67: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableEntry.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 23: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 34: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 34: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Errors in 'jar:file:/home/miso/Java%20libs/guava-r08/guava-r08-gwt.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java'
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 32: The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 220: Nullable cannot be resolved to a type
            [ERROR] [databasemanager] - Line 224: Nullable cannot be resolved to 
'com.google.common.primitives.Booleans.BooleanArrayAsList'
            [WARN] [databasemanager] - Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
    [INFO] [databasemanager] - http://127.0.0.1:8888/databasemanager/
    [INFO] [databasemanager] - Module databasemanager has been loaded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in guava-r08, http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=586, which leads to the exception message "The import javax.annotation cannot be resolved".

There are two solutions:

- Either use guava-r09, where this bug has been fixed,
- or download [jsr-305.jar](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/lib/jsr305.jar?r=146) and add it to your classpath.

Comment: I can confirm that adding new version of guava-r09.jar and guava-r09-gwt.jar solved the problem!

Comment: That link to jsr-305.jar is broken. Where can I find it now?

Comment: @Rosarch: For example here: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v8.0/lib/jsr305.jar

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you're supposed to be using the GWT repackaged Guava stuff at all. I'm guessing that's just for internal use. You should download the latest Guava release [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/list) and include both the guava and guava-gwt jars from that. You'll then need to inherit modules based on the packages you want to use. The collect package would require

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
```

Comment: I added both guava and guava-gwt jars to my classpath and to my /lib folder of war, then pasted your module name. However, I got this error:  Unable to find 'com/google/common/collect/Collect.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source

Comment: @Xorty: Sounds like for whatever reason the guava-gwt jar isn't on the classpath when GWT tries to compile.

Comment: I have user library in classpath that contains both of jars :S want to see?

Comment: @Xorty: Well, that XML file definitely exists in the guava-gwt jar so I'm not sure what to say. Something probably isn't configured right. In any case, I don't think I can help any more with this (I've only set up a project using GWT and Guava once myself).

Comment: @CollinD - sure, I just added som new update, maybe you'd like to see that :)

Comment: I did say the _latest_ Guava release!

Comment: Correct, I assumed I have one :/ Chrises answer just popped in my head "wtf I have guava-r08 not -r09" :)

Comment: I didn't realize you needed to download both guava and guava-gwt, I was trying to use the -gwt only and not having much success.  +1 for that :)

Comment: This answer is wrong, the OP is referencing the private internal Guava inside GWT instead of the real public Guava.

Comment: @mP.: Isn't that exactly what I said when I said "I don't think you're supposed to be using the GWT repackaged Guava stuff at all."?

Answer (score 5):

You are referencing `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.Lists` from the repackaged Guava goodies in GWT. You'll need to include the guava jars (both guava and guava-gwt), and change your imports to use `com.google.common.collect.Lists`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using maven, just modify the pom.xml with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>${guava-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>${guava-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and make use of

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
```