# Trouble with GWT and Guava

Tags: java, gwt, guava

I am having difficulty make GWT work with Guava. I added `guava-r09-gwt.jar` to my classpath, and `<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>` (copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005687/guava-libraries-and-gwt)) to my `*.gwt.xml` file. However, I still get the following error:

> [ERROR] Line 99: No source code is
>   available for type
>   com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.Lists;
>   did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?

The referenced line is:

```
List<String> suggs = Lists.newArrayList();
```

If I try the following `inherits` tag:

```
  <inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Lists"/>
```

Then GWT totally fails - going to the app in the browser gives a 404, and no URL appears in Eclipse's development panel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll notice that `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.Lists` is not actually in the Guava jars. Try instead referencing `com.google.common.collect.Lists` and you should have some more success.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy I had same problem (and asked here at StackOverflow), check it out [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322559/whats-the-correct-name-for-guava-module-in-gwt-application). Hope that helps! And as Collin pointed out, you're having wrong import, don't use thirdpardy libraries from there.